# Jquery filter not working with jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using ajax to retrieve a web page like that:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "/Cadastros/pagina_busca_correios?cep=" + cep,
            type: "Get",
            DataType: 'Html',
            success: function (data) {                       
                 var webdata = data;
                 var tables = $(webdata).filter('table');
                 alert(tables);                                                
            }
   });
```

I am able to print the html in data return but after creating the jquery object and apply filter I get noting. It is like a have an error with my javascript.

PS. I know I have 4 tables inside this html string, so I would like to filter the tables and iterate through them to perform actions. Those elements inside the DOM has no id´s or names that I could use to select straight forward.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are `table` elements in the root of webdata?

Comment: It's hard to say what you're doing wrong without seeing the actual returned html.  I suspect you want `find` instead of `filter` but I have no way to know.

Comment: Are your tables wrapped in another tag if so then use find instead of filter

Comment: Note that you'd normally write the dataType in lowercase and the type in uppercase, not that it would matter as jQuery sorts it out, but using uppercase for the first letter only is bad form, at least a little bit, same goes for assigning new variables that does the exact same thing as the original one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) doesn't find child elements, [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) does. To make it sure it works either way, append the data to a new element and use `find()` :

```
var tables = $('<div />').append(data).find('table');
```

and you can use `data` directly, no need for another variable.